# Ruby run shell command in a specific directory

Tags: ruby, shell, command

I know how to run a shell command in Ruby like:

```
%x[#{cmd}]
```

But, how do I specify a directory to run this command?

Is there a similar way of shelling out, similar to `subprocess.Popen` in Python:

```
subprocess.Popen(r'c:\mytool\tool.exe', cwd=r'd:\test\local')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can use the block-version of `Dir.chdir`. Inside the block you are in the requested directory, after the Block you are still in the previous directory:

```
Dir.chdir('mydir'){
  %x[#{cmd}]
}
```

Comment: The things like this that Ruby does with blocks never cease to amaze me.  Ruby constantly makes my other languages feel clunky and overcomplicated.

Comment: Dir.chdir is ok if you have a single thread. For multiple threads look at the other answers here.

Comment: This is great for single-threaded scripts.  It is not safe for launching multiple processes in parallel.

Answer (score 13):

Ruby 1.9.3 (blocking call):

```
require 'open3'
Open3.popen3("pwd", :chdir=>"/") {|i,o,e,t|
  p o.read.chomp #=> "/"
}

Dir.pwd #=> "/home/abe"
```

Answer (score 4):

also, taking the shell route

```
%x[cd #{dir} && #{cmd}]
```

Answer (score 4):

The closest I see to backtricks with safe changing dir is `capture2`:

```
require 'open3'
output, status = Open3.capture2('pwd', :chdir=>"/tmp")
```

You can see other useful Open3 methods in ruby docs. One drawback is that `jruby` support for `open3` is rather broken.

Comment: Using the `:chdir` option of any `Process.spawn`-based invokation (`system`, `popen3`,...) seems to be thread-safe for launching parallel processes, too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but try to use Dir.pwd to get the current directory and save it somewhere. After that use Dir.chdir( destination ), where destination is a directory where you want to run your command from. After running the command use Dir.chdir again, using previously saved directory to restore it.

Comment: You can also use the block-version of `Dir.chdir`. Inside the block you are in the requested directory, after the Block you are still in the previous directory.

Comment: @knut You should make that an answer - I like it! I was going to suggest something crazy like `Dir.chdir(Dir.pwd.tap {Dir.chdir('d:\test\local'); #otherstuff})` as I wasn't aware chdir could take a block

Comment: @AbeVoelker You are right, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10148325/676874)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and solved it by putting both commands in back ticks and separating with '&&':

```
`cd \desired\directory && command`
```