# Ruby: How to get the correct full path of a source file after a chdir?

Tags: ruby, path, chdir

See the following example:

```
puts __FILE__                           #test.rb
puts File.expand_path(__FILE__)         #C:/TEMP/test.rb

Dir.chdir('..')
puts __FILE__                           #test.rb
puts File.expand_path(__FILE__)         #C:/test.rb
```

After a (global) `chdir` the `expand_path` returns a wrong result.

**How can I get the correct result?**

I tried to use the 2nd parameter of `File.expand_path`:

```
puts File.expand_path(__FILE__, 'temp') #C:/TEMP/test.rb
puts File.expand_path(__FILE__, 'c:/temp') #C:/TEMP/test.rb
```

But to use it, I must know the path of `__FILE__`.

The command `require_relative` seems to ignore all `chdir`-actions. So I have the hope, there is a way to get the 'real' directory of a file.

Remarks:

- I know the [block-version of Dir.chdir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10148325/676874) - for my specific task i can#t use it.
- My actual solution: I store the fullpath before I change the directory (I could also store `Dir.pwd` before I change the directory).

Comment: Don't understand what the expected output is.. Could you help ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I look for the real location of my source file. In my example it is in c:/temp.

Comment: Check this - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-realdirpath , if helpful.

Comment: why can't you do it before relative? And, did you do a gem?

Comment: I don't use a require_relative in my code. But when I tried to solve my problem I recognized, that require_relative has no problem with change of directories. So I thought there may be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__FILE__` builtin is an instance of `String` class:

```
puts __FILE__.class 
# ⇒ String
```

That means you should not expect any voodoo magic from it. It stores the relative path, this file was loaded at.

```
ruby C:\TEMP\test.rb        # ⇒ __FILE__ == 'C:\TEMP\test.rb'
cd C:\TEMP && ruby test.rb  # ⇒ __FILE__ == 'test.rb'
```

In ruby 2.0 was new builtin `__dir__` [introduced](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__). It looks like what you are looking for, in case `2.0`-only solution is OK with you.