# Split the string to get only the first 5 characters

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, chef-infra

I would like to go to the location 
`/var/log/src/ap-kernelmodule-10.001-100`

But looks like my code has to deal with 
ap-kernelmodule-10.002-100, ap-kernelmodule-10.003-101 etc.
I would like to reach the location with a split string and execute my command. 
eg : /var/log/src/ap-kernelmodule-10./

This ruby script for a Linux machine, so I used Mixlib:: ShellOut.

```
begin  
cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("command run here" , :cwd => 
'/var/cache/acpchef/src/ap-kernelmodule-10xxx')
 cmd.run_command
end
```

Comment: MAybe helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147913/ruby-run-shell-command-in-a-specific-directory/10148325#10148325

Comment: If you want the first 5 characters of a string, you can use the `String#[]` method with a range. `"012345"[0...5] => "01234" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't be in multiple `cwd`s simultaneously. To run the command for each directory that matches the pattern, you can use `Dir#glob`:

```
Dir.glob('/var/cache/acpchef/src/ap-kernelmodule-10*').each do |cwd|
  Mixlib::ShellOut.new("command run here", cwd: cwd).run_command
end
```

Comment: begin
cwdkernel =  Dir.glob('/var/cache/acpchef/src/ap-kernelmodule-10*')
        cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("command run here", :cwd => 'cwdkernel')
        cmd.run_command
end------------
how come this is not running the command.

Comment: There's no "do"

Comment: begin
       cwd_kernel = Dir.glob('/var/cache/acpchef/src/ap-kernelmodule-10*')
        cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("command run here", :cwd => cwd_kernel )
        cmd.run_command
         log 'run'
     rescue Exception => e
       end -----------so it works only with do??
else it will not

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite get on what you really want to achieve. Question is rather ambiguous.

You know you would like to go to `/var/log/src/ap-kernelmodule-10.001-100` and run a command, the most obvious way is you could just use:

```
execute "command run here" do
 cwd "/var/log/src/ap-kernelmodule-10.001-100"
end
```

But if you would like to run a command for each directory like you said in `ap-kernelmodule-10.002-100`, `ap-kernelmodule-10.003-101` etc. with `/var/log/src/ap-kernelmodule-10.*/` sequentially.

Then you could do with:

```
Dir.glob("/var/log/src/ap-kernelmodule-10.*").each do |folder|
  execute "command run here" do
   cwd folder
  end
end
```

Additionally, parallel resources execution is not possible natively in chef (AFAIK).
So, the possible workaround is to use `bash` or `ruby_block` resource to construct commands to be executed in `xargs`, `parallel` or similar tools.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually, even if the folder is ap-kernelmodule-10.002-100 or ap-kernelmodule-10.003-101, I need the command to run. Because according to my script the version keeps changing. Sorry for not being very clear. For some machines its one folder and for other machine its the other.